# Create an icecast2 URL for OGG

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, streaming, audio-streaming

I have made an DarkIce server following the answer on this question: [Stream sound card output to icecast2 via darkice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225271/stream-sound-card-output-to-icecast2-via-darkice).

And it works fine on players that support. In the **Icecast2 Status** I have a link for both the m3u and the XSPF. But I need to stream it into a html5  and therefore I need to have a path for an **.ogg**

How can I configure the icecast2 to have this path available?

Link to the server screen (already set as vorbis in darkice):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path you are looking for is the `MountPoint` in the `Darkice.cfg`:

```
[icecast2-0]
#format          = mp3 <- for mp3 config
format      = vorbis
bitrateMode     = cbr
bitrate         = 128
quality         = 0.8
server          = localhost
#ends with .ogg for vorbis radio
mountPoint      = YourStation.ogg
#no extension needed for mp3
#mountPoint      = YourStation
```